# Backfill erroneous temporal values in pandas dataframe if previous time step is under limit

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe of temporal data with ID, Time and Value as columns. Now I know that value can never go below, say, 90 and any value lesser than that is erroneous. So how would I backfill this erroneous value (with a little jitter) provided that the previous value for that ID was recorded no more than 2 hours ago?

Basically:

- Find values < 90
- If previous value for ID was recorded less than 2 hours ago: **Backfill**
- Else delete row

Answer (score 0):

first drop the values <= 90 and which have prev value > 2hrs

set the less than 90s within 2hours to nan, ffill these

some dummy data

```
time = pd.Series(np.random.randint(15e17, 15e17 + 1e16, 1000), 
dtype='datetime64[ns]').sort_values()
values = np.random.normal(100, 5, 1000)
ids = np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' :ids, 'time' : time, 'value' : values}, index=np.arange(1000))
```

method to apply when grouping by id

```
def replace_data(df):
    df['time_to_prev'] = df.time - df.time.shift() 
    df = df.loc[(df.value > 90) | (df.time_to_prev < pd.Timedelta(hours=2))]
    df.loc[df.value < 90, 'value'] = np.NaN
    df.value = df.value.ffill()
    return df[['id', 'time', 'value']]

df.groupby(['id']).apply(replace_data).reset_index(drop=True)
```